# Typescript can't find module, and "Cannot find Map"

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Expected behaviour:
I'm expecting my code to compile without errors
And expecting import statement to work

Actual behavior:
When I run tsc app.ts, I get this error:

```
../node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts:750:72 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the lib compiler option to es2015 or later.

750 static props<K, V>(map: Resolvable<Map<K, Resolvable>>): Bluebird<Map<K, V>>;
```

Playground Link:

I also get another error in my code editor:

```
File '/Users/harry.gothold/Documents/api-call-weather/src/app.ts' is not a module.
```

This is the test I'm trying to run:

```
import * as app from '../src/app';
// import * as chai from 'chai';
//import { result } from '../app';
var chai = require('chai');
var sinon = require('sinon');
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('result', function() {
it('should be called called with weatherDescription', (done) => {
expect(result).to.eventually.equal('clear sky');
done();
});
});`
```

This is the original ts code:

```
let request = require('request');
let promise = require('bluebird');

function getData() {
return new promise((resolve:any, reject:any) => {
request('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=2643743&APPID=99eaec08987344591490f9a6ee213155', {json: true},
(err:any, res:any ,body:any)=> {
resolve(body.list[0].weather[0].description);
reject(err, 'Sorry, there was an error fetching the data');
});
});
};

function result(weatherDescription: any) {
console.log(The weather today is ${weatherDescription});
}

getData()
.then((weatherDescription:any) =>{
result(weatherDescription)
})
.catch((err:any) => {
throw(err)
});

module.exports = {
getData: function() {},
result: function() {}
}`
```

And this is my tsconfig file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
/* Basic Options /
"target": "es6", / Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. /
"module": "commonjs", / Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. /
"lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"], / Specify library files to be included in the compilation. /
// "allowJs": true, / Allow javascript files to be compiled. /
// "checkJs": true, / Report errors in .js files. /
// "jsx": "preserve", / Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. /
// "declaration": true, / Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. /
// "declarationMap": true, / Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. /
// "sourceMap": true, / Generates corresponding '.map' file. /
// "outFile": "./", / Concatenate and emit output to single file. /
// "outDir": "./", / Redirect output structure to the directory. /
// "rootDir": "./", / Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. /
// "composite": true, / Enable project compilation /
// "removeComments": true, / Do not emit comments to output. /
// "noEmit": true, / Do not emit outputs. /
// "importHelpers": true, / Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. /
// "downlevelIteration": true, / Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. /
// "isolatedModules": true, / Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

/* Strict Type-Checking Options */
"strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
// "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
// "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
// "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
// "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
// "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
// "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

/* Additional Checks */
// "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
// "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
// "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
// "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

/* Module Resolution Options */
// "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
// "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
// "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
// "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
// "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
// "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
// "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
"esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
// "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

/* Source Map Options */
// "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
// "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
// "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
// "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

/* Experimental Options */
// "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
// "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`Map` is introduced in ES2015, so in your `tsconfig.json` set the `target` to `es2015` as in

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "strict": true  
  }
}
```

Ref:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map